# Uses of word OR

Tags: grammar

Whether it’s the evergreen comedy FRIENDS or HOW I MET YOUR MOTHER or medical drama like GREY’S ANATOMY or the mysterious and sociopath detective streak SHERLOCK or a family show like FULL HOUSE every .

In above sentence what could be the substitute of word OR as it has been used so many times.

Comment: "I think it's A, B, C, D or E."

Comment: Your text isn't a "sentence" - it's just a [dependent clause](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/dependclterm.htm) providing additional context for some preceding or following "primary statement" clause that you haven't included. You could in principle replace all except the last ***or*** in such a list by commas, but I don't see that as a very good approach in this specific case. Nor do I think there's anything inherently "undesirable" about repeating that word. It's just that the sheer number of examples seems meanderingly pointless.

Comment: 1. As a matter of style. It is really uncomfortable to read all those upper case names. You could perhaps use quotes or italics.  2. I don't understand what 'every' is doing at the end of your clause.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I think the OP cut the sentence off at "every"... also, it's actually an industry standard thing (that I personally abhor) to make a title in all uppercase. Just pointing that out. Personally, I'd rather it were in Italics. [Here's](http://www.dutimes.com/international-sitcom-new-trendsetter/) the actual article.

Comment: @klenium That doesn't actually work in this case. This is not a simple list. It's a list of several categories.

Comment: @Catija How does it not work? "Whether it's the evergreen comedy such as FRIENDS or HOW I MET YOUR MOTHER, medical drama like GREY'S ANATOMY, the mysterious and sociopath detective streak SHERLOCK, or a family show like FULL HOUSE, every (...)." I think klenium can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the full text (thanks Catija):

> Whether it’s the evergreen comedy *Friends* or *How I Met Your Mother* or
>   medical drama like *Grey's Anatomy* or the mysterious and sociopathic
>   detective streak *Sherlock* or a family show like *Full House* every show
>   has influenced us so much that nowadays we are using their lingo only.
>   - *[Delhi Times](http://www.dutimes.com/international-sitcom-new-trendsetter/)*
>
> [Titles changed from upper case to italic title case for easier
>   reading.]

The idea behind the structure of this sentence is to illustrate the wide range of "shows" that have influenced everyday language. This range is emphasised by the use of repetition, which is a very common rhetorical device.
The repetition of a word (in this case *or*) at the beginning of a phrase is known as **anaphora** and, as *[literary devices.net](http://literarydevices.net/anaphora/)* claims, it goes back a long way:

> Anaphora, possibly the oldest literary device, has its roots in Biblical Psalms [and is] used to emphasize certain words or phrases.

*[American Rhetoric.com](http://www.americanrhetoric.com/figures/anaphora.htm)* gives this example:

> "That my heart has been troubled, that I have not sought this
>   nomination, that I could not seek it in good conscience, that I would
>   not seek it in honest self-appraisal, is not to say that I value it
>   the less. Rather, it is that I revere the office of the Presidency of
>   the United States."
>
> *Adlai Stevenson, 1952 DNC Presidential Nomination Acceptance Address*

Sometimes the "rules" that we learn about English are broken for effect.

Comment: +1 For *Sometimes the rules we learn ... are broken for effect*.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, you are looking for alternatives to the word *or* for those times when you'd like to vary things up a bit.

1. Commas.  Example: A, B, C or D.
2. Vs.  Example: Let's consider A vs. B vs. C.
3. Introduce your list with something that sets the list up as a list of alternatives.  Example: We considered our options -- A, B, C, and D.